# How can I support both a local SQL Server CE and remote SQL Server in my desktop C#/WPF application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am developing a Windows .NET 4 C#/WPF desktop application for a client. Originally, they wanted only a standalone desktop app, so I was planning on using SQL Server CE for the database. Now, they want the app to also support an environment where the application is run by multiple users on the local network.

I'm not sure what I need to do to support both environments in my application. This seems like a pretty common scenario. What is the best approach to handle this requirement?

Comment: What framework are you using for data access?  Linq2SQL, Entity Framework, or plain ADO.Net?

Comment: I haven't decided yet, but I'm leaning towards EF. I'm open to suggestions. I've only worked with ADO.Net before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're taking the connection information from the connection strings section in the config file, you can switch DB's by simply changing the connection string. Here are examples of connection strings for both SQL Server CE and SQL Server 2008:

- http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce
- http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

You can do this both with the Entity framework (although the connection string contains some extra metadata there) and plain ADO.NET.

Comment: As long as he uses adequate technique or queries.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess I'm more concerned with actually getting the database set up on the remote SQL Server at installation time. I'm guessing I'd need some kind of scripting to make that happen?

Comment: @stefan +1. @PIntag Yes, you would need to setup the SQL server separately e.g. with [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) scripts.

Comment: So how is this typically handled? Would I provide some kind of separate database install package (along with my application installation package) that could be run by a DB admin?

Comment: Yes. It's common to have one script that creates the initial version of the DB and then update it with "update scripts". A DBA would have to execute them. You could of course create an installer that can run the scripts, but it may be simpler just to create the necessary scripts and hand them over to your DBAs. These scripts should be maintained in your source control system along with the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

Can you rely on the users always having internet access? It may be better to simply have them connect to a remote database via WCF and not use a local database at all.

If your users will often be disconnected from the network, consider using SQL Server CE Client Agent. This is a DLL you can link with SQL CE that will connect to an IIS Server Agent service, and merge with an external database. Each time your SQL CE app connects it gets the latest version of data, then disconnects. There was an old article on MSDN [Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164090.aspx), I believe this is still supported in SQL CE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I agree that with your reasoning to choose a remote DB approach, but that is not the route my client wants to take for this project.